# Getting Paypal API response

Tags: api, paypal

I am trying out the PayPal API Developer Account, and am in the midst of creating a test payment. I have followed the steps stated [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/partners/checkout/create-checkout-button/).

However, what I want to do is to extract the JSON response from the orders API, in which I would be using in Tibco. The request has been successfully made and is reflected in the Sandbox account. But I am unsure how I can obtain the URL that returns the JSON response from the orders API.

I am new to Paypal API integration and I would really appreciate any help provided.